# Await error when loading mobilenet from tfjs

Tags: tensorflow, async-await, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs, mobilenet

I am following this tutorial https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-models/tree/master/mobilenet

When I try to load the module with:

```
require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node')
const mobilenet = require('@tensorflow-models/mobilenet')


const model = await mobilenet.load();
```

I am getting this error on the console (using tfjs-node):

```
const model = await mobilenet.load();
              ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

I don't know what's going on! Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

await needs to be used in an async function.

```
(async () => {
  const model = await mobilenet.load();
})()
```

Comment: And since await need to be in an async function it cannot sit in the script as a statement outside of all the functions. This kind of usage can also raise some @babel issues in electron.

Comment: It is in an async function. I don't understand what you mean here

Comment: Just adding to your answer, it is a bit unclear in my opinion that an await cannot be without any functions, or functions without async.